# How to solve cors?

Tags: angular, firebase, cors, cors-anywhere

I am fetching images url from db, but they are not displaying, application is deployed on firebase hosting and images are from my own server
https://editor.mousawir.com/editor?type=facebook_event

Comment: This is not a front end issue. If you are in charge of backend development then enable CORS in server side or ask the backend developer to do so.

Comment: issue is its hosted on firebase, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

you have to enable CORS access from any origin please follow the link and configure the setting that matches your server.

https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: u mean from where they are loading or where they are beign called?

Comment: my files are on firebase whey the images have to show..

Comment: you have to enable CORS on Server Side

Comment: problem solved by adding <FilesMatch ".(eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|svg|less|jpg|png)">
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch> on origin

Comment: great! if the problem is resolved then tick mark this answer because it will help the others